# Django custom save not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have the following model:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #...
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print 1
        is_created = False
        if not self.pk:
            print 2
            is_created = True
        super(Info, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 3
        if is_created:
            print 4
            signals.info_created.send(sender=self.__class__,info=self)
```

now I have those print statements to keep track of what is going on.when I run either `Info.create(...)` or

```
info = Info(...)
info.save()
```

I get the following output:

```
1
3
```

which suggests that the `if not self.pk` statement evaluated to false. Now I assume this is because I have a custom primary key that needs to be given on the creation of that object. So here is my question: **is my assumption correct? Regardless if it is or is not, how can I get this custom save to cooperate?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base.py Model:

```
def _get_pk_val(self, meta=None):
    if not meta:
        meta = self._meta
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
```

meta.pk point on user_id, meta filled from kwargs in constructor before calling create or save

```
class Info(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print 1
        is_created = False
        if not self.pk:
            print 2
            is_created = True

        self.pk = 20 #set pk before super call to pass validation

        super(Info, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print 3
        if is_created:
            print 4


Info.objects.create(text='wew')
#prints 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: that's what I expected. Notice that my question has two parts, please answer the second

Comment: So this does not answer my question. My problem is that the line `if not self.pk` is evaluating to false, when I need it to evaluate to True. And this field must be a primary key because of optimization and consistency in the database

Comment: Also, your code will cause an error because you cannot ever have a blank primary key...

Comment: i can have blank primary key, before calling super method